# Tkinter full screen not working in Python 3.10 for Mac OS

Tags: python, tkinter

I just upgraded Python from 3.8 to 3.10 and the Tkinter full screen attribute no longer works as it used to.

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.6 (Macbook M1). I had Python 3.8 installed on this Macbook and it has been working fine until I upgraded Python today.

Here is the code and the root window does not show in full screen for Python 3.10:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

root = tkinter.Tk()

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated because I'm stuck. I have also seen other problems with my UI in Python 3.10 so if I'm not able to solve these problems I may revert back to Python 3.8 :(

**UPDATE 1** I've noticed that my Macbook makes a bleep sound when I run with the full screen attribute but it does not if I comment out that row.

I've also noticed that it makes the same bleep sound when I type on the keyboard e.g. in an Entry widget. It did not use to do that in Python 3.8, so may be related.

**UPDATE 2** I am able to do a somewhat ugly workaround by using a delay and setting the full screen attribute after 250 ms with a root.after(...) function. Then it works. It does not look very nice since empty white backgrounds flash by before the actual program opens.

Comment: The bleep and the fact it works when you delay means the window probably doesn't have focus for some reason. Try adding `root.focus_force()` before `root.attributes` and see if that helps.

Comment: Good point. Based on your tip I experimented with both focus_force and grab_set before setting the attributes. I am able to get rid of the bleep sometimes, but not consistently. And it does not resolve the fullscreen problem unfortunately. Will trouble shoot more based on this and see if I can make it work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `root.wm_attributes()` instead.

### Example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')
root.mainloop()
```

Yet another way to do this is by calling tcl as follows

```
root.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", root._w, "plain", "none")
```

use only either of the methods.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both those things and they do not make any difference.